# GWT Product Mode AssertionException Catch ? HOW?

Tags: gwt, gxt

in product mode in GWT the assertion is not available which is good, but because of a GXT error I get an assertion error and because the necessary classes are not available all I get is a com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException error in the browser and it's not enough to properly debug it. The reason why I need this is because in my custom framework I created a class that's responsible for error handling

```
            GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
                addError(e);
            }
        });

            public void addError(Throwable ex)
            {
                if(!ex.getClass().equals(AssertionError.class))//(ex instanceof AssertionError))
                {
                    this.addError(ex, true);
                }
            }
```

as you can see I've tried to capture the error but I'm unable to in production mode. I somehow need to be able to sepcify the exception so I can filter it. All errors get into the logs and I don't want these errors to appear there

GXT Error => http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171409-RowEditor-AssertionError&p=709005

thanks help

By Egg

Comment: What version of GXT are you running?

Comment: There are error logs on your server which might tell you the source of the error

Comment: i use gwt2.4 and gxt2.2.5....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable assertions in your compiled code, and this is done very similarly to how you would do this in a standard jvm, using the `-ea` flag. Instead of passing this to the jvm though, it needs to be passed to the Compiler class (or put in the program args if running from eclipse, or some other tool).

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions for the list of all args you can pass to the compiler